# How to change the color of tabsHighlight in ionic

Tags: html, colors, tabs, ionic3, highlight

I have a iontabs and I want to change the highlight when it active

Here is the code of html:

```
<ion-tabs mode="md" tabsPlacement="top" tabsHighlight="true" tabsLayout="icon-start">
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabBadge="" tabBadgeStyle="" tabTitle="TODAY" tabIcon="ios-star" ></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

and here my code of css (i could change only the text and icon color) :

```
$tabs-md-tab-text-color-active: #000;
$tabs-md-tab-icon-color-active: #000;
$tabs-md-tab-highlight-color-active: #000;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, overriding ionic variable for tab highlight (from https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) is not working.

there is also a thread regarding changing background color of active tab here:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/changing-tab-color-in-ionic/39457/15

you can add this into your app.scss instead

```
.tabs-md .tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tab colors can be changed using Sass variables. See the conference app for some example theming:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/tree/master/src/theme